# What's the difference between "sea port" and "maritime port"?

Tags: meaning, differences, meaning-in-context

> Road transport is not the only sector concerned. LNG is also used in
>   maritime and inland waterway transport. The Commission therefore
>   proposes the installation of fuel stations in leading European **sea and
>   maritime ports (for 2020 and 2025, respectively)**.

([source](http://www.europolitics.info/sectorial-policies/commission-plans-to-equip-eu-with-alternative-fuel-stations-art347467-46.html))

What's the difference between *sea port* and *maritime port*?

Comment: The source is private. "Bonjour, l'accès à cet article est réservé aux abonnés. Veuillez vous identifier dans le cadre ci-dessous." Is there not a glossary or something similar in the document?

Comment: Just a few minutes ago it was public. No, there is no glossary.

Comment: These look like being terms of art used in a particular context and with particular meanings in the relevant EU legislation. If I had to hazard a guess, I would say that a sea port was on the sea, but that a maritime port could be on some kind inlet, such as a fjord. Are there any maritime lawyers among us?

Comment: @BarrieEngland the first thing they are likely to say, is to look at the proposal rather than a piece of journalism about it. As it happens, doing so here does so even for laymen like ourselves, as the article made a mistake.

Comment: @Jon Hanna. Looks like. Pity we can't see the full text of the report.

Comment: @BarrieEngland funny, that link worked for me on first click, but doesn't now. It's been syndicated at http://3e-news.net/show/30396_eight%20million%20recharging%20stations%20for%20electric%20vehicles%20should%20be%20in%20the%20eu%20by%202020_en/ and http://www.publics.bg/en/news/9658/Commission_Plans_to_Equip_EU_with_Alternative_Fuel_Stations.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None, *maritime* means "of the sea" and when *sea* is used as a noun adjunct it means "of the sea", so *maritime port*, *sea port* and the closed compound *seaport* all mean a port that has direct access to the sea (coast, inlet, natural harbour). You may or may not decide to include a fluvial port on a river, but that goes equally for either word. You normally would not include dry ports (a terminal with a direct overland connection to a seaport), in either.

The [original proposal](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/themes/urban/cpt/doc/com%282013%2918-2-directive_en.pdf) says:

1. Member States shall ensure that publicly accessible LNG refuelling points for
   maritime and inland waterway transport are provided in all **maritime ports** of the
   Trans-European Transport (TEN-T) Core Network by 31 December 2020 at the
   latest.
2. Member States shall ensure that publicly accessible LNG refuelling points for inland waterway transport are provided in all **inland ports** of the TEN-T Core Network, by 31 December 2025 at the latest.

(Emphasis mine).

In rewriting from the proposal to produce the article the author made a mistake. My guess is they were trying to decide between keeping the term and writing "maritime and inland ports" or changing it to "sea and inland ports" on the basis that *sea* is a better known word than *maritime* and some readers might not understand *maritime*, and in trying to pick between the two they accidentally wrote *sea and maritime ports*

It's clearly not a matter of their using *sea* to mean something other than *maritime* because the time for the "sea ports" in the article matches the time for the "maritime ports" in the original.

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific meaning of *maritime* which is opposed to *sea* in normal usage: but Europe does contain many ports not on the sea, both with sea access only by canal (such as Amsterdam or Antwerp) and with no realistic sea access at all (such as Strasbourg and Belgrade; River and canal trade, being cheaper than road or rail though slower, is still important). It seems likely that the author wanted a term for 'non-sea ports', and chose something neutral but clear in context.

Comment: The proposal they were writing from used "inland port" but they chose something unclear in the rewrite, and moved the "maritime" from the 2020 deadline it had in the original to the 2025 deadline for inland ports. It's simply an error,